# How do you print accented characters on an Epson FX-890 printer and retain the printer control sequences?

Tags: c#, printing, dot-matrix

I have a text document created by a C# program that has accented Spanish characters in it ("ñ", for example), as well as printer control characters.  I am trying to print the document to an Epson FX-890 printer (we must use a tractor feed printer as we need to create multi-copy documents due to government regulations in the countries these files will be printed in).  In my text editor (I'm using EditPlus) the character shows properly with character code F1.  If I print directly from my text editor the character shows properly, but my printer control characters are also simply printed, not acted upon.  If I copy the file to the printer (from a cmd window (Windows 10)) the printer control characters are acted upon, but the "ñ" shows as plus over minus in one character set (chosen with the printer control characters), or an italicized "q" in the only available other character set.

So, I'm looking for ideas on how to resolve this issue and have the printer control characters acted upon and the accented characters print properly.  Here is the initial control string I am sending ("[esc]" being the x1B escape code):

[esc]@  - Resets printer

[esc]x1 - Print quality NLQ

[esc]p0 - Italics Off

[esc]5  - Pitch 12

[esc]M  - 6 Lines per inch

[esc]2  - Carriage return

Comment: Is the culture on your computer settings Spainish?  It appears the Encoding is set wrong either on printer or computer settings.

Comment: There's also [esc]R7 or [esc]R11 which selects one of the two Spanish character sets.  Have you tried those? https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf

Comment: I'm not using the Spanish culture on the computer, but I do in the C# code use the ES language when creating the file.  As seen in file, the character is correct.

Comment: I've tired the [esc]R12 (Latin America), and just tried R7 and R11.  Still no luck, but then I saw the actual character mappings.  Tired 7C which normally maps to "|" and that is exactly what was printed.  I notice they say for the table on R-41 of the referenced document (which I don't think I've come across before) that this is for the Helvetica typeface.  Not sure what typeface this is using (I'm  not specifying one), it is fixed width.  I'll see if I can change the typeface.